# Why don't my "FN + Volume up/down" keys work?

Tags: audio, windows-vista, fn-key, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba laptop with Windows Vista. I turned on my computer once and it had a little red 'X' on the volume speaker. I reinstalled the driver (I'm not sure if I did that right though), and now the sound works, but I can't adjust the volume with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> keys, or Mute.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my Pavilion (Vista) and the problem was an incompatibility issue between HP's drivers and a Vista update. I was unable to overcome it till Microsoft released a patch for this.

Comment: I have the same problem with Windows 7 + Cooler Silent Fn function

Answer (score 2):

The Fn key functionality will depend on driver and/or software from the manufacturer. Check the driver/downloads site for your model, and one of them should restore this, assuming it exists for Vista.